# std::list::erase does not invalidate other iterators and references

Tags: c++, list, erase

I read in cppreference that `erase` does not affect iterators and references other than erased ones. But if I don't understand why following code does not work:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main()
{
  std::list<int> lst;
  lst.push_back(5);
  lst.push_back(10);
  lst.push_back(20);

  int i = 0;
  for (auto it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end(); ++it) // FIRST LOOP
  {
    if (i == 1) { lst.erase(it); }
    ++i;
  }

  for (auto el : lst) // SECOND LOOP
  {
    std::cout << el << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

First loop never stops which causes `Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`. But I don't erase everything works fine.
So what is the problem?

UPD:
Tried to change

```cpp
...
for (auto it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end(); ++it) // FIRST LOOP
...
```

to

```cpp
...
auto end = lst.end();
  for (auto it = lst.begin(); it != end; ++it) // FIRST LOOP
...
```

but it did not help

Comment: Alternatively, with C++20, you could use `std::erase_if`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9jY8o1YYc)

Comment: *I read in cppreference that erase does not affect iterators and references other than erased ones.* -- `lst.erase(it);` -- You erased `it`, so how is `++it` going to work?  What you read is exactly what is happening.

Comment: Erasing `it` invalidates `it`.   The loop will then increment `it` (before checking the end condition).    Incrementing an invalidated iterator (in fact, any operation other than assigning it to be a validated iterator) gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

When you delete the element at `it`, you cannot increment `it` anymore. Therefore, you need to use this instead:

`if (i == 1) { it = lst.erase(it); }`

Also, you need to solve not to increment `it` in this case. So likely the increment would go inside the loop:

```
int i = 0;
for (auto it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end(); ) // FIRST LOOP
{
    if (i == 1)
    {
        it = lst.erase(it);
    }
    else
    {
        ++it;
    }

    ++i;
}
```

Comment: In other words, `it` invalidated and no longer usable to so much as find other nodes right here: `lst.erase(it);`

Comment: @Peter It is happening, at least when `i == 1`. In that case `lst.erase(it)` invalidates `it`. Then `++it` is also invalid.